# http4s - how create blaze client with limited count of threads?

Tags: scala, http4s

I trying to create blaze client with limited number of threads like this:

```scala
object ReactiveCats extends IOApp {
  private val PORT = 8083
  private val DELAY_SERVICE_URL = "http://localhost:8080"
  
  // trying create client with limited number of threads
  val clientPool: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(64)
  val clientExecutor: ExecutionContextExecutor = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(clientPool)

  private val httpClient = BlazeClientBuilder[IO](clientExecutor).resource

  private val httpApp = HttpRoutes.of[IO] {
    case GET -> Root / delayMillis =>
      httpClient.use { client =>
        client
          .expect[String](s"$DELAY_SERVICE_URL/$delayMillis")
          .flatMap(response => Ok(s"ReactiveCats: $response"))
      }
  }.orNotFound

  // trying to create server on fixed thread pool
  val serverPool: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(64)
  val serverExecutor: ExecutionContextExecutor = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(serverPool)

  // start server
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    BlazeServerBuilder[IO](serverExecutor)
      .bindHttp(port = PORT, host = "localhost")
      .withHttpApp(httpApp)
      .serve
      .compile
      .drain
      .as(ExitCode.Success)
}
```

[full code and load-tests](https://github.com/va-anufriev/jvm-microservice-http-battle/tree/master/apps/reactive-cats)

But load-test results looks like one thread by one request:
[image]

How I make restrict numbers of threads for my blaze client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy from my commment.

Answer for performance issue is properly setup for Blaze client - for me this is .withMaxWaitQueueLimit(1024) parameter.

Answer (score 4):

There are two obvious things that are wrong with your code:

1. you're creating an Executor without shutting it down when you're done.
2. you're using the `use` method of the `httpClient` Resource inside the HTTP route, meaning that every time the route is called, it will create, use and destroy the http client. You should instead create it once during startup.

Executors, like any other resource (e. g. file handles etc.) should always be allocated using `Resource.make` like so:

```scala
  val clientPool: Resource[IO, ExecutorService] = Resource.make(IO(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(64)))(ex => IO(ex.shutdown()))
  val clientExecutor: Resource[IO, ExecutionContextExecutor] = clientPool.map(ExecutionContext.fromExecutor)

  private val httpClient = clientExecutor.flatMap(ex => BlazeClientBuilder[IO](ex).resource)
```

The second problem can easily be fixed by allocating the httpClient before building the HTTP app:

```scala
  private def httpApp(client: Client[IO]): Kleisli[IO, Request[IO], Response[IO]] = HttpRoutes.of[IO] {
    case GET -> Root / delayMillis =>
      client
        .expect[String](s"$DELAY_SERVICE_URL/$delayMillis")
        .flatMap(response => Ok(s"ReactiveCats: $response"))
  }.orNotFound

…

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    httpClient.use { client =>
      BlazeServerBuilder[IO](serverExecutor)
        .bindHttp(port = PORT, host = "localhost")
        .withHttpApp(httpApp(client))
        .serve
        .compile
        .drain
        .as(ExitCode.Success)
    }
```

Another potential problem is that you're using `IOApp`, and it comes with its own thread pool. The best way to fix that is probably to mix in the `IOApp.WithContext` trait and implement this method:

```scala
  override protected def executionContextResource: Resource[SyncIO, ExecutionContext] = ???
```

Comment: I fixed code as mentioned in your answer and get fixed threads to count, thanks! But now I'm getting awful performance - ~30 RPS vs ~500 (code from the question). I tested both versions with a global pool app and a fixed pool. If you have ideas about this will be cool.

Comment: Answer for performance issue is properly setup for Blaze client - for me this is `.withMaxWaitQueueLimit(1024)` parameter.